# How to use whereEqualTo multiple times in same query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat application. I am uploading the messages to firestore with fields docId(document id), textMessage(actual message), fromId(id of the user who sent the message), toId(id of user to whome the message is sent), createdAt(time at which the message is sent).
I want to fetch the message to show in the chatLog activity.
I am fetching the messages using the following query

```
val reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("messages")
            .whereEqualTo("fromId", currentUser.userId)
            .whereEqualTo("toId", otherUser.userId)
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

But I think the query is not working properly and is returning all the messages which have `fromId` and is not checking for the `toId` field.

Please tell me is there a way to get all the messages which have both `fromId` and `toId` fields.

`otherUser.userId` is NnbqRLY0haTYgtat3LYZQAEl1oP2
and `currentUser.userId` is lrFpBpZJQXdieUwSMnXAop4vugt1

"I am good. What about you" is showing in the current signed in account.
And in other account, "hi" is showing.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Since we can't see the value of `otherUser.userId` along with the database data that should match it, there's not much we can do to tell you what's wrong. Please edit the question to show the actual values used in the query (perhaps just hard code the strings) along with the documents that you think should match the query. We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the instructions you provide.

Comment: @DougStevenson I read the last part on the run. That's true, Doug. So Divyansh, please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.